# Face Recognizer in OpenCv Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, face-recognition

I am creating an app which has Face Recognizer module.
 I am get a demo project of Face Recognizer From
https://github.com/yaylas/AndroidFaceRecognizer . 
 

My Problem is when I Recognize a Face and a face is not stored in DB of this app then App give  me a another face which matches most with that face.
Can anyone know how to get a different result when there is Unknown face Recognization with this app?

I have only one Training set of Face. and I want to test that the Face which is captured for sample is match with training images or not.

Comment: The algorithm computes the distance from your test image to the closest found match in the database, so you need predefine a threshold of tolerance/rejection of this distance, and re-tune it by running few tests on your data

Comment: I want only Train one Person Face Detection. and Recognize the face with different faces. but My app show me the result same.

Comment: you need to make your question clearer !